# jQuery animations queue up - stop() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm having problems with a piece of coding for animation effects (selected from a drop down as well as the duration). The animations continue to queue up and run. I've tried `.stop()` - with all settings, `clearQueue()`, `finish()`, `removeAttr('style')`, nothing seems to be doing the trick (`removeAttr` wouldn't really help me either way since the animations play through class changes as well as style).

Here is my code currently:

```
var time = 2000;
$('.view-tab').click(function() {

if ($('.time').val() == '2') {
    time = 2000;
} else if ($('.time').val() == '5') {
    time = 5000;
} else if ($('.time').val() == '10') {
    time = 10000;
} else if ($('.time').val() == '7') {
    time = 7000;
};

if ($('.effect').val() == 'rightleft') {
    setInterval(function () { 
        $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').stop(true, true).animate({right: "500px"}, "slow", function () {
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').appendTo('#viewer-slider_content .slider');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').addClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:last-child').removeClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').css('right', '0');
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    }, time).removeAttr('style');
} else if ($('.effect').val() == 'leftright') {
    setInterval(function () { 
        $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').stop(true, true).animate({left: "500px"}, "slow", function () {
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').appendTo('#viewer-slider_content .slider');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').addClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:last-child').removeClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').css('left', '0');
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    }, time);
} else if ($('.effect').val() == 'fade') {
    setInterval(function () { 
        $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "0"}, "slow", function () {
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').appendTo('#viewer-slider_content .slider');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').addClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:last-child').removeClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').css('opacity', '1');
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    }, time);
} else if ($('.effect').val() == 'topbottom') {
    setInterval(function () { 
        $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').stop(true).animate({top: "500px"}, "slow", function () {
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').appendTo('#viewer-slider_content .slider');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').addClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:last-child').removeClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').css('top', '0');
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    }, time);
} else if ($('.effect').val() == 'bottomtop') {
    setInterval(function () { 
        $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').stop(true).animate({bottom: "500px"}, "slow", function () {
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').appendTo('#viewer-slider_content .slider');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:first-child').addClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider .tab-content:last-child').removeClass('current');
            $('#viewer-slider_content .slider').css('bottom', '0');
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    }, time);
}});
```

if anyone could help me would be much appreciated.

Comment: please add som HTML as well

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, being generated through asp. goes something like this: <div id='viewer-slider_content><div class='slider'><div id='1' class='tab-content></div>...all the way to <div id='4' class='tab-content'></div></div></div> and inside the .tab-content is just a <p>some text</p>. The .effect and .duration is select boxes with options (dropdown menu). the .view-tab is just a button that calls colorbox modal with the #viewer-slider_content as the content.

Comment: It seems you have taken on a to difficult solution. You need to give a better html then that

Comment: at the moment I'm just using a refresh when the viewer box closes, but I was hoping for a better solution than that